# pivot group by year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, pivot

How can I group a pivot by the years?

```
SELECT YEAR(bolfecha) ,pvt.[C],PVT.[P]
FROM 
(select bolfecha, bolestado
from Tbboleta) as src

PIVOT
(
COUNT(bolestado)
FOR bolestado IN ([C], [P])
) AS pvt;
```

Bolfecha it's the column that have the dates it's like 2005-02-01
Using this code give me every year instead of grouping them only by year 2005, then all the registers for 2006, and so on...

I'm trying to coun how much 'C' and 'P' are registered on the column bolestado, and that works but I can't just group them by the year, help pls
It gives me something like this

```
2005    53  3
2006    2   0
2006    2   0
2006    6   0
```

.
.
.

2005 it's the only one that actually grouped and I don't even know why
Edit: Oh I know why 2005 it's the only one grouped it's because it only have 2005-12-31 in every 2005 row so that's why

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your data using `GROUP BY` first then use `PIVOT` to turn row data into columns.

First, grouping as intended:

```
SELECT YEAR(bolfecha) [Year], bolestado, COUNT(*) ItemCount FROM Tbboleta
GROUP BY YEAR(bolfecha), bolestado
```

This produces this result:

```
Year  bolestado     ItemCount
2005          C     10
2005          P     7
2006          C     3
2006          P     8
```

Then now you can apply the pivot to this result-set by using:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT YEAR(bolfecha) [Year], bolestado, COUNT(*) ItemCount FROM Tbboleta
   GROUP BY YEAR(bolfecha), bolestado
) RawData
PIVOT (
    MIN(ItemCount) FOR bolestado IN (C, P)
) PivotData
```

And this gives you this result:

```
Year     C      P
2005    10      7
2006     3      8
```

`PIVOT` can pick the values you want and create columns for these values based on a simple aggregate function (`SUM`, `MIN`, `AVG`, `COUNT` ...) but you can't group at the same time. If you need a group you need to do this separately using `GROUP BY` before doing the `PIVOT`.

Comment: Hi it' gives me this error Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 23
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'Rawdata'. Thanks for your answer I'm just copypasting the code maybe there is something left?

Comment: I haven't run the code so it might not be strictly valid but I wanted to share the idea of how I would approach it. I will try to create some test data and test it. But the error you got seems very simple to solve just add an alias to YEAR(bolfecha). I will edit the answer to reflect that

Comment: @NaruLopo I edited the answer to fix the issue you got. Give it a try now.

Comment: omg it works, thank you so much :D A last question How can I make the columns C and P to be 'Canceladas' and 'Pendientes'  instead of just showing C and P

Comment: If the original values are 'P' and 'C' but you want to rename only the headers of the columns in the output you can enclose the whole query in another outer SELECT that assigns your new aliases.
Like this:
SELECT [Year], C Canceladas, P Pendientes FROM (<Original query goes here>) GroupedPivot

Comment: yeah It worked thank you so much I was really having troubles with this, you taught me so much, thanks